# What do you call someone who is banned by law to leave their country? and What is the verb for banning somebody this way?

Tags: word-choice

There are many occasions that law might ban someone from leaving a country. For example, in Iran, if a man's wife requests her dowry and the man refuses to pay and hides himself, she can use legal provisions to ban him from leaving the country. What is the verb in English to describe `to ban someone from leaving a country via law because of a crime, etc.` and what is called someone who has been given imposed this ban?

Comment: You're looking for something similar to *house arrest*, or on *bail*, but these conditions are imposed on a person awaiting trial. A verb though....?

Comment: Another example for this type of *house arrest* and putting ban on leaving country was imposed on leaders of the Green Movement following Iran's 2009 controversial presidential election

Comment: The person is under "travel restrictions".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here in the UK its commonly known as a *travel ban* or generally as *[exit restrictions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_movement#Exit_restrictions_in_certain_countries)*.

Comment: The asker seems to be looking for the word for the person subject to these restrictions, not the name of the restrictions themselves.

Comment: Ah yes in the that case id suggest prefixing with, respectively,.  'the subject of' or 'subject to' .